# Nginx custom PHP error_pages with different header status codes and body contents

Tags: php, error-handling, nginx

using Nginx 0.8.54 : I setup PHP error page to do redirections for some links and 404 for others and display custom HTML body.
nginx

```
server {
 error_page 404 = /err/error.php?error=404;
}
```

error.php

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/blah" ){
    header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('location: http://localhost/ ');
}else
    header('Status: 404 Not Found');

echo 'This is a custom Error Page';
?>
```

Nginx does the redirection with no problem but for the 404 custom page, Nginx sends the 404 headers and displays the default Nginx page instead of the 'This is a custom Error Page' text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not setting the `header('Status: 404 Not Found');` twice ? (e.g. this is already a 404 error page)

Comment: according to the documentations "error_page 404 = /err/error.php?error=404;" does not set a status code